# How do I rewrite this probability statement using $\limsup$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, limsup-and-liminf, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I have the following problem.

> We have $Y_n$ independent random variables defined on $(\Omega, F, \Bbb{P})$ s.t. $$\Bbb{P}(Y_n=1)=p~~~\Bbb{P}(Y_n=0)=1-p$$ for $p\in [0,1]$. We define $A_0=0$ and $A_n=\sum_{k=0}^n Y_k$. Now I assume $0<p<1$ I need to use the Borell-cantelli lemma to sho that almost surly there is no index $N$ such that for $n\geq N$ the sequence $(A_n)$ is increasing.

Now I first need to rewrite the statement using $\limsup$. As I understood it I need to show that $\Bbb{P}(\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_{n+1}=A_n)=1$

But since I'm a bit unsure using $\limsup$ I wanted to ask if this is correct, so if I rewrote the scentence correclty with mathematical language or not. If not could you maybe explain this a bit because as I said I'm always a bit confused using $\limsup$ in stochastics.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You seem to have switched $A_n$ to $S_n$.  And it looks as if the sum should be increasing, especially since $E[A_n]=np$

Comment: @Henry Oh sure this is a tipo from my part. Sorry I corrected it. I hope now everything makes sense. But is it then correct that I need to show $\Bbb{P}(\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_{n+1}=A_n)=1$

Comment: It makes no sense to me.  $A_{n+1}-A_{n} =Y_n$ and that is not almost surely $0$

Comment: @Henry Sorry what does not make sense to you, my try of solving the exercise or the exercise? So I mean that's exaclty the exercise our Prof gave us in the lecture

Comment: @Wave your question makes no sense in several ways. The random sums $\sum\limits_1^n Y_k$ is (not strictly) increasing for each $Y_k \geq 0.$ Furthermore, $\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} A_{n+1} = A_n$ does not define an event because $n$ has two meanings in this expression. Maybe what you want to show is that $(A_n)$ never becomes _strictly_ increasing, but this is easy: that would entail that $Y_k = 1$ for every $k \geq N$ and this has probability zero: $P(Y_k = 1, \text{ for all } k \geq N) = \lim\limits_{m \to \infty} P(Y_k = 1, N \leq k \leq N +m) = \lim\limits_{m \to \infty} p^m = 0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note
$$\begin{aligned}P(\{\omega:A_n(\omega)\textrm{ is increasing after some }N\})&=P(\{\omega:\exists N \textrm{ s.t. }Y_n(\omega)=1,\,\forall n\geq N\})=\\
&=P(Y_n=0\textrm{ finitely often)}=\\
&=1-P(Y_n=0\textrm{ i.o.})\end{aligned}$$
Now $(Y_n)_{n \in\mathbb{N}}$ are IID and then by BC II
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}P(Y_n=0)=\infty \implies P(Y_n=0\textrm{ i.o.})=1$$
and therefore our set has measure zero.

Comment: sorry to ask again, but I asked me, what would happen if I would take $\Bbb{P}(Y_n=1)=p$ and $\Bbb{P}(Y_n=-1)=1-p$? Because then I could not say that $Y_n=0$ i.o.  So I mean then it would not increase if we have $+1-1+1....$ right?

Comment: @Wave from the context of the question I deduced that 'increasing' is to be intended as 'strictly increasing'. Therefore if $P(Y=-1)=1-p$, we find $A_n$ is increasing after some $N$ on the set of events $\{Y_n=-1 \textrm{ finitely often}\}$.